# Grails gorm and mongodb: embedded array is being persisted as a map with numerical keys

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to save a Map to a document. Some of the Maps values are Maps but one in particular is an Array. This array is being saved as a Map with numerical keys instead of an array.

```
class Post {

    ObjectId id
    String title
    String slug
    Date date
    String type
    Boolean published
    Map data

}
```

This is the way the data is in the database, the way that Gorm returns it from the database, and the way I'd like it to remain after being saved:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("577e9f1f78917ff50e1285e8"),
"slug" : "slug",
"title" : "title",
"published" : true,
"type" : "news",
"date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T07:00:00.000Z"),
"data" : {
    "content" : "post content here",
    "thumb" : "thumb.jpg",
    "featured_photo" : "featured.jpg",
    "tags" : "tags",
    "meta" : {},
    "video" : null,
    "interest" : "surf",
    "photos" : [ 
            {
                "source" : "image1.jpg",
                "caption" : "caption1",
                "thumb" : "thumb1.jpg"
            }, 
            {
                 "source" : "image2.jpg",
                 "caption" : "caption2",
                 "thumb" : "thumb2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("577e9f1f78917ff50e1285e8"),
"slug" : "slug",
"title" : "title",
"published" : true,
"type" : "news",
"date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T07:00:00.000Z"),
"data" : {
    "content" : "post content here",
    "thumb" : "thumb.jpg",
    "featured_photo" : "featured.jpg",
    "tags" : "tags",
    "meta" : {},
    "video" : null,
    "interest" : "surf",
    "photos" : { 
            "0" : {
                "source" : "image1.jpg",
                "caption" : "caption1",
                "thumb" : "thumb1.jpg"
            }, 
            "1" : {
                "source" : "image2.jpg",
                "caption" : "caption2",
                "thumb" : "thumb2.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can specify that "data.photos" should be stored as an array and not as a map?

Answer (score 0):

My solution as of right now is to leave the "data" property un-mapped and then use the subscript operator to access and save the property as is rather than having Gorm force it into a Map.